# Android: How do you send data to a website securely

Tags: android, database, security

I was just wondering how you could send data to a website securely so then the website can display the information upon log in of the user (of the website). I am not that familiar with MySQL or anything like those. The data is only text but it would be great if anyone can include examples of the code.

Cheers
Nick

Comment: If you don't really know much about it, this won't be entirely easy.  At the very least, use SSL.

Comment: Are you only interested in transmission security or do you also want the data to be decryptable only by the end user even once it is in the database?

Comment: If your server supports SSH you might want to looki into SSHing the information using jsch library.

Comment: ok well does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Do you use SSL on the website? You need a secure server.

Comment: Well I can if I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common for people to create a RESTful API to allow your client to access the data.  This API should be over HTTPS.  It is important that you **do not trust the device**.  You should assume that this is like any other web application backend and that an attacker can access it directly.